# Checking for nullable columns from a JdbcTemplate with Spring and Kotlin

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, jdbctemplate

In my Spring application with Kotlin, I am reading a sql table that has many nullable columns. For a nullable column I using this if-expression:

```
  if (rs.getObject("ordernumber") != null) rs.getInt("ordernumber") else null
```

Is there an easier way than writing an if-expression for each nullable column?

I have simplified the example to one nullable column, but of course I have many more nullable columns with String, Integer, Timestamp and so on.

```
    fun getEmployeePayRecord(employee: Employee): List<EmployeePayRecord> {

        val rowMapper: RowMapper<EmployeePayRecord> = RowMapper { rs, _ ->
            EmployeePayRecord(
                uuid = rs.getString("uuid"),
                workingDay = rs.getTimestamp("working_day").toLocalDateTime(),
                orderNumber = if (rs.getObject("ordernumber") != null) rs.getInt("ordernumber") else null
            )
        }

        return jdbcTemplate.query(
            """select uuid
                    , working_day
                    , ordernumber
                 from plrv11.employee_pay_record
                where employee_number = :employeeNumber
                order by working_day
            """, rowMapper, employee.employeeNumber
        ).toList()
    }
```

---

EDIT

I have taken up M. Deinum's and David's ideas and added extension functions, like this:

```
fun ResultSet.getIntOrNull(columnName: String): Int? {
    val result = getInt(columnName)
    return if (wasNull()) null else result
}
```

Comment: I suggest a helper method and to use `wasNull` instead of doing a get twice. Something like `int result = rs.getInt("ordernumber"); return rs.wasNull() ? null; result;`. Also `query` already returns a list so why the `toList`? If you use `queryForStream` and do `toList` this beats the purpose and you can just use a regular `query` instead.

Comment: @M.Deinum Indeed - toList() is superfluous. I threw it away. Thank you very much. I completely overlooked it.

Comment: @M.Deinum The helper function would have to be a generic function, since I have strings, integers, BigDecimals and timestamps. The helper function should be able to handle all types. Hmmm, tricky.

Comment: No it wouldn’t you should have multiple helper functions for the different types, instead of shoehorning it into a single method.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thank you for your help. Greetings to the Netherlands.

Comment: For extra luxury you can convert your `getXXXOrNull` into an extension functions on `ResultSet` so that you could call: ` orderNumber = rs.getIntOrNull("ordernumber")

Comment: @DavidSoroko Great idea. I allow myself that luxury of extension functions. Thank you very much.